# invalid url with python requests library

Tags: python, python-requests

I have this URL

```
'http://blah/Block?OnStreet=Hoyt+Street&Borough=Brooklyn&CrossStreetOne=Schermerhorn+Street&BoroughCrossStreetOne=&CrossStreetTwo=Livingston+Street&BoroughCrossStreetTwo=&CompassDirectionOne=&CompassDirectionTwo=&BlockType=stretch'
```

which correctly return a JSON response in the browser but I am trying to create this URL in python using the requests library and I am having no luck

```
args={'OnStreet': 'Hoyt Street','Borough': 'Brooklyn','CrossStreetOne': 'Schermerhorn Street','CrossStreetTwo': 'Livingston Street'}

resp=requests.get('http://blah/Block?',data=args)

print resp.json()
```

gives me

```
<Response [400]>
{u'ErrorDetails': [u'Block Type must be provided.', u'On Street must be provided.', u'Borough must be provided.', u'Cross Street One must be provided.', u'Cross Street Two must be provided.'], u'ErrorMessage': u'Request is Invalid'}
```

what am I doing wrong? I only need to fill in the parameters that I filled in so that is not the issue. I am unable to format it correctly

using python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

You should just change the part that says `data=args` to `params=args`

This is because you are doing a get and not a put where `data=args` would be appropriate.